# How to dynamically create triggers INSTEAD OF DELETE where multiple foreign keys pointing to the same table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, cascade

I have following tables `parent` and `child1`.

`ParentID1` and `ParentID2` in `child1` table are pointing to `ParentID` in `parent`.

[image: Parent and Child1 tables]

Schema:

```
-- Table creation logic
--parent table

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Parent]
(
   [ParentID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
   [Data] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_Parent] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ParentID] ASC)
)
GO

-- Child table

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Child1]
(
    [Child1ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ParentID1] [bigint] NULL,
    [ParentID2] [bigint] NULL,
    [Data] [varchar](10) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Child1] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Child1ID] ASC)
)
GO

-- foreign key constraints
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Child1] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Child1_ParentID1] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ParentID1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Parent] ([ParentID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[child1] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Child1_ParentID2] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ParentID2]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Parent] ([ParentID])
GO

-- inserting data into the tables
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (1, 'test')
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (2, 'test')
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (3, 'test')
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (4, 'test')
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (5, 'test')
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (6, 'test')
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (7, 'test')
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (8, 'test')
    
INSERT INTO Child1 VALUES (1, 1, 2, 'test')
INSERT INTO Child1 VALUES (2, 2, 3, 'test')
INSERT INTO Child1 VALUES (3, 3, 4, 'test')
INSERT INTO Child1 VALUES (4, 4, 5, 'test')
INSERT INTO Child1 VALUES (5, 5, 6, 'test')
INSERT INTO Child1 VALUES (6, 6, 7, 'test')
GO
```

I want to remove respective records from child as well whenever I delete a record from parent. I tried 'cascade on delete' but got error - " may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths".

So, I moved to creating triggers to handle this. Since I have a large DB, I want to dynamically create the triggers on the tables.
So, I loop on the following metadata table(LF_DB_Relations) which contains parenttable, childtable, primarykeycolumn and foreignkeycolumn to create the triggers dynamically:

[image]

Since there are multiple parent-child entry for same parent and child, Creation of trigger fails when it tries to create the second "INSTEAD OF DELETE" trigger on the same table.

[image: error message while creating trigger]

Here is the query I am using to create the triggers dynamically:

```
DECLARE @childtable varchar(50);
DECLARE @fkcolumn varchar(50);
DECLARE @parenttable varchar(50);
DECLARE @pkcolumn varchar(50);

DECLARE @RowCnt BIGINT = 0;
DECLARE @count INT;
SET @count = 1;

-- get a count of total rows to process 
SELECT @RowCnt = COUNT(0) FROM dbo.LF_DB_Relations;

WHILE @count<= @RowCnt
BEGIN
    select
    @childtable = childtable,
    @fkcolumn = fkcolumn,
    @parenttable = parenttable,
    @pkcolumn = pkcolumn
    FROM dbo.LF_DB_Relations
    WHERE ID = @count

    EXEC('CREATE TRIGGER '+ 'Delete_' + @parenttable + '_Purging_' +@count+
       ' ON ' + @parenttable +
       ' INSTEAD OF DELETE ' +
        'AS ' +
        'BEGIN ' +
         'SET NOCOUNT ON; '+
         'DELETE FROM ' + @childtable +' WHERE ' + @fkcolumn +' IN (SELECT ' +  @pkcolumn + ' FROM DELETED) ' +
        ' DELETE FROM ' + @parenttable + ' WHERE ' + @pkcolumn + ' IN (SELECT ' +  @pkcolumn +' FROM DELETED) ' +
        'END');     

    PRINT @childtable;
   SET @count = @count + 1;
END;
```

What is wrong in my dynamic trigger query? How can I create single trigger on each parent table with delete queries for all the FKs of all the children tables?

Comment: Just as an aside - you are aware that there are built-in metadata views, etc from which foreign key information can be obtained, aren't you?

Comment: I don't get your design nor your sample data. You seem to point parents and children at each other.

Comment: @siggemannen, If you refer the schema code- 2 columns of the child1 table are pointing to same column(ParentID) of parent. so only children are referencing parent.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring a `parent` table multiple times, because in the `child` you have more then one foreign keys to it. So, your code is creating (or at least trying to create) multiple `INSTEAD OF DELETE` triggers, which is not allowed.

Let's say the data looks like:

[image]

and you need to create only one trigger for the `Categories` table.

So you need to group the data like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #LF_DB_Relations;

CREATE TABLE #LF_DB_Relations (
    childtable NVARCHAR(255),
    fkcolumn NVARCHAR(255),
    parenttable NVARCHAR(255),
    pkcolumn NVARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO #LF_DB_Relations (childtable, fkcolumn, parenttable, pkcolumn)
VALUES ('OrderDetails', 'OrderID', 'Orders', 'OrderID'),
       ('OrderDetails', 'ProductID', 'Products', 'ProductID'),
       ('Products', 'CategoryID', 'Categories', 'CategoryID'),
       ('Products', 'SupplierID', 'Categories', 'CategoryID');

SELECT * FROM #LF_DB_Relations;



    DECLARE @childtable varchar(50);
    DECLARE @fkcolumn varchar(50);
    DECLARE @parenttable varchar(50);
    DECLARE @pkcolumn varchar(50);

    
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #LF_DB_Relations)
    BEGIN

        SELECT TOP 1 @parenttable = parenttable
        FROM #LF_DB_Relations;

        SELECT 'CREATE TRIGGER '+ 'Delete_' + MAX(parenttable) + '_Purging' + CHAR(10) +
           ' ON ' + MAX(parenttable) + CHAR(10) +
           ' INSTEAD OF DELETE ' + CHAR(10) +
            'AS ' + CHAR(10) +
            'BEGIN ' + CHAR(10) +
             'SET NOCOUNT ON; '+ CHAR(10) +

             STRING_AGG(CAST('DELETE FROM ' + childtable + ' WHERE '  + fkcolumn + ' IN (SELECT ' +  pkcolumn + ' FROM DELETED);'  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), CHAR(10)) + 
              STRING_AGG(CAST('DELETE FROM ' + parenttable + ' WHERE '  + pkcolumn  + ' IN (SELECT ' +  pkcolumn + ' FROM DELETED);'  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), CHAR(10)) + 

           
            'END' 
        FROM #LF_DB_Relations
        WHERE parenttable = @parenttable;

    
        DELETE FROM #LF_DB_Relations
        WHERE parenttable = @parenttable;

    END;
```

You need to handle each parent table once and in its trigger to delete all `child` rows.

Please, note the above code is not ready for production. You need to:

- use [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) around the table and column names
- can add the schema for each table
- you may need or may not to use `STRING_AGG` for the parent table `DELETE` statement (for example if multiple columns from the parent table are used as foreign keys to child tables)
- you may have hierarchy of foreign keys in the child tables - image for particular parent you need to delete data from two child tables but one of child table  has FK to the other - in such case the order of deletion is important;
- when building the dynamic T-SQL trigger definition, use CHAR(10), CHAR(13) and others to format the code; if you build one line definition it will be hard for people who script the trigger to debug or change it to read it;